# My plugin doesnt work in Opera

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, image

I wrote some code for flip my image by CSS and jQuery, but this solution doesn't work in Opera, I tried couple of hours to fix it, but I didn't make it

Please let me know what's wrong if you can guys.

CSS

```
.tiled-gallery-item {
  -webkit-perspective: 800;
  -moz-perspective: 800;
}
.tiled-gallery-item a img.flipped {
  -webkit-transform: rotatex(-360deg);
  transform: rotatex(-360deg);
  -o-transform: rotatex(-360deg);
}
.tiled-gallery-item a img {
  -webkit-transform-style: preserve-3d;
   transform-style: preserve-3d;
  -o-transform-style: preserve-3d;
  -webkit-transition: 1s;
  -o-transition-duration: 1s;
  transition: 1s;
}
```

jQuery

```
jQuery(function(){
    jQuery('.tiled-gallery-item').hover(function(){
        jQuery(this).find('a img').addClass('flipped')(function(){
            jQuery(this).removeClass('flipped');
            jQuery(this).addClass('flipped');
        });
    });
```

I'm pretty sure, that's all about CSS, but I tried everything...
    });

Comment: This line is a micro horror `.addClass('flipped')(function()` and your simultaneous `removeClass` and `addClass` makes no point.

Comment: Also can you post some HTML just to make sure the selectors and the nesting is fine?

Comment: it's fine because works in Chrome, Firefox and IE

Answer (score 0):

```
jQuery(function( $ ) {  // Fingers saver :) (DOM ready and secured $ alias)

    $('.tiled-gallery-item').hover(function() {
        $(this).find('a img').toggleClass('flipped');
    });

});
```

Comment: thanks, but im sure it's not the point of that Opera's problem